# Use input from form1.textbox to mysql connection in form2

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can i use the input received from a textbox in Form1 to make a connection with mySQL in form2.
Now my program is like this:

Form1 opens and asks for Server, Username, Password.
There are 3 buttons that will open different forms using form2 module, in form2 is the SQL connection string.

I have right now this at the connection string in form2:

```
Public Const cnString As String = "datasource=" & DBSelector.txtServer.Text & ";" _
                                  & "username=" & DBSelector.txtUsername.Text & ";" _
                                  & "password=" & DBSelector.txtPassword.Text & ";" _
                                  & "database=" & DBSelector.txtDatabase.Text & ";"
```

Now im stuck with this error: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."
I'm new with Visual Basic, and i cant fix the problem.
I think its because Form2 is a module and not a Public Class.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To refer to another Form "in live", you must have a variable that it contains the instance of the second Form.

   For refernce a new Form from the Main-Form code, you can use the same variable which it was the Second-Form its created.

   **In Your Case** - reference from the called form to the caller form, you can  1. store the Forms instance in a static ariable in the Form itself, 2. pass it in parameter to Second Form constructor (the New() Sub).

   or you can skip all the topic by sending your information directly to the constructor, so:

   **the Main-From Code - DBSelector in your case:**

   ```
   Public Class DBSelector

       ...

       Public Sub LanchSecondForm()
           Dim form2 As Form2 = New Form2(txtServer.Text, _
                                          txtUsername.Text, _
                                          txtPassword.Text, _
                                          txtDatabase.Text)

           form2.Show()
       End Sub

       ...

   End Class
   ```

   **the Second-Form code:**

   ```
   Public Class Form2

       ...

       Public cnString As String
       Public Sub New(datasourcePrm As String, _
                      usernamePrm As String, _
                      passwordPrm As String, _
                      databasePrm As String)
           cnString = "datasource=" & datasourcePrm & ";" _
                    & "username=" & usernamePrm & ";" _
                    & "password=" & passwordPrm & ";" _
                    & "database=" & databasePrm & ";"

           InitializeComponent()
       End Sub

       ...

   End Class
   ```
2. Const reresent an absolute value, known at compile time. its impossible assign a "dynamic"  value, so:

   ```
   Public a As String
   Public Const b As String = a       'error: a its a variable
   Public Const b As String = "abc"   'correct
   ```

Hope I understood and helped.

Comment: I think i understand it a little bit right now, but so i have nothing to edit in form1(DBSelector)? Because when i try it like this i cant connect to the database. Sorry for the many info i need but i'm very new with Visual Basic.

Comment: @SCALETTA i edited my answer. Before I was wrong, I thought that DBSeletor is secondary, now I understand it the main.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but i have forgot to say that Form2(gModule) is a Module, and i cant put "Dim gmodule As gModule = New gModule". Again sorry that i'v forgotten to say that its a module... Im very new with Visual Basic and i dont know every function and class there is in VB..

Comment: 1. delete my code 2. create a public variable in the module so `Public cnString As String` 3 . from the DBSelector use this code:  `gModule.cnString = = "datasource=" & DBSelector.txtServer.Text & ";" _
                                  & "username=" & DBSelector.txtUsername.Text & ";" _
                                  & "password=" & DBSelector.txtPassword.Text & ";" _
                                  & "database=" & DBSelector.txtDatabase.Text & ";"`

Comment: Alright now it works!!! Many many many thanks. I could never have done this without you :)